# iOS: UIActionsheet (or UIPopoverController view) becomes zombie

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, zombie-process

I have an UIViewController. Within it the user may launch an UIActionsheet or a popover. If the device rotates, the UIViewController is intentionally released. The problem is that the UIActionsheet / popover lives on and becomes a zombie to haunt me afterward. The user may click a button in the zombie and crash the application. I tried to call [actionsheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO] in dealloc or shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. No effect. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this post: [dismiss actionsheet][1]

[1]: [iPad crash with UIActionSheet displayed from child view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404261/ipad-crash-with-uiactionsheet-displayed-from-child-view-controller). I made a mistake trying to recall the actionsheet by searching through the UIViewController view's subviews or calling the viewWithTag method. Strangely enough, it did return a non-nil object. But using this object to call dismissWithClickedButtonIndex does not work.

The autor of the post suggests using an UIActionSheet pointer and dismiss the actionsheet in viewWillDisapper works. For the above specific application, I found it worked better to dimiss the actionsheet in dealloc.

Comment: Mark your question as having been answered then.

Comment: Patience grasshopper. Newer users have to wait a grace period before they can accept their own answer.